# Connection refused when used docker Compose with postgis and nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, nestjs, postgis

My composed container after `docker-compose up` always ends up in `connection refused` error. Following is my docker compose file and my docker file and the error is listed below. The application is a nestjs based graphql application with postgis as database and redis as queuing and cache storing mechanism.

My build command is

```
docker-compose --env-file=docker.env up
```

My docker compose file is

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  cleanilo-admin-project:
    image: cleanilo-admin-project
    build: .
    command: npm run start:prod
    ports:
      - '3001:80'
    env_file: docker.env
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - cleanilo-docker-network

  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    env_file: docker.env
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD-SHELL', 'redis-cli ping | grep PONG']
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5

  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis:12-3.3-alpine
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    env_file: docker.env
    networks:
      - cleanilo-docker-network
    healthcheck:
      test: 'pg_isready --username=$POSTGRES_USER && psql --username=$POSTGRES_USER --list'
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: on-failure

networks:
  cleanilo-docker-network:
    name: cleanilo-docker-network
```

My DockerFile is

```
FROM node:18-slim
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./
USER node
RUN npm install --force  --legacy-peer-deps --no-cache
COPY --chown=node:node . . 
COPY docker.env .env
EXPOSE 3001
RUN npm run build
```

Content of docker.env

```
# POSTGRES DOCKER ENV
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="9&G*3Y9asZ"
POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
POSTGRES_DB="database"

#DATABASE
DATABASE_HOST="postgres"
DATABASE_USER="postgres"
DATABASE_PASSWORD="9&G*3Y9asZ"
DATABASE_NAME="database"
DATABASE_HOST="5432"
```

My nodejs is throwing a `ECONNREFUSED` error. The image is used are redis:alpine and [postgis/postgis:12-3.3-alpine](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/)

Help me debug this, the nodejs based error message reads
[image: Errors in log of application image]

This is my ormconfig.ts file
[image: Orm Config file]

[image: Using ormconfig in app.module.ts]

Comment: Redis is missing `networks`. However, the error is about Postgres (5432 port). Other than the missing `networks` block, your docker-compose.yml is valid, and the app container can reach PG. So there must be something else.

Comment: This looks like a ```typeorm``` issue. Can you share the file where connection is established using nestjs?

Comment: Is that a typo in ```docker.env``` for ```Database_host```? You have mentioned port as host

Comment: Yeah it was @vicki

Comment: I had a similar issue once, this went away when I set ```synchronize``` to false, and reinstalled the pg driver. It sounds weird, but this fixed, have you tried this?